# Turn Off Anti-Aliasing For Bitmap

Tags: android, mobile, smoothing

I've recently started testing for my game on other peoples phones. For some reason the whole game is getting really "blurry" for their phones, but not for mine. All of them has got a higher android version then I do.

I've tried finding a good answer around the web for this, but all I can find is the answer for if you are using the res/drawable folders. I am loading my images from the assets folder with a special load method. I am then stretching them out when I draw them onto the screen with the "c.drawBitmap()". I am drawing using an "android.view.View".

So now, anyone that has the answer for turning the anti-aliasing off for bitmaps when creating 8-bit games. It would be an impossibility for me to resize the images before rendering them onto the screen, because of me creating an image from an integer array, that refreshes with a rate of about 60 fps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That blurriness, is most probably because of low resolution of your bitmaps. It may be fine on the test device of yours, but when you use them on higher resolution screens you will either get raw/pixelated or blurry/AA'd results after scaling. An appropriate solution is to have different images for different resolutions, or to be more accurate; densities. Android already do the choosing part:

```
ldpi
mdpi
hdpi
...
```

I am assuming you know these identifiers.

Put your high resolution image to res/drawable-hdpi, low resolution to res/drawable-ldpi etc.

Comment: I would still have a problem, and that is the creation of the pixel bitmap that I'm creating over and over again aprox. every 15 milliseconds. You I do need a way to actually turn it off.

Comment: You shouldn't create the `Bitmap` over and over, You should load it on memory once and draw it on Canvas over and over. But if you insist you can  turn off AA, you need to pass a `Paint` object with AA closed. you can achieve this by using `paint.setAntiAlias(false);`, you will pass this to `drawBitmap()`, probably last argument.